# Linux LaTeX template installation issue

Tags: installing, templates, linux

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to install the `IEEE template` to create a `.tex` document. I have tried both methods of the following tutorial, but none worked:
https://softwareexperiments.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/installing-ieeetrans-and-the-ieee-bibtex-style-for-latex-in-ubuntu/

When I try to compile it, it outputs errors like these:

```
! I can't find file `nullfont'. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input nullfont Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input nullfont Transcript written on mfput.log.

`! I can't find file `pplr7t'. <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pplr7t Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pplr7t Transcrip`t written on mfput.log. grep: pplr7t.log: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand what's wrong, I was able to make it work on a 10.04 seamlessly.

Comment: This post is also discussed on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=20406). Recommended there: real TeX Live installation instead of taking the 2009 version of the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend to install package `texlive-fonts-recommended` which is provided in the regular Ubuntu repository. Perhaps the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is also necessary.